# Useful or cool Tasker recipes

Tags: applications, tasker

In a similar vein to [this question](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/487), I'm interested in finding any useful recipes for [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/).

I've found several [profiles](http://tasker.wikidot.com/profile-index) and ["Step Throughs"](http://tasker.wikidot.com/step-throughs) on their wiki, but would be interested in any others that people have found helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a good one I found on Lifehacker a while back.

http://lifehacker.com/5611003/build-a-find-my-iphone-clone-for-android

I changed a few things when I did it, like allow the text to come from any phone and send the reply to that phone, and making the SOS text a passphrase so that nobody accidentally sent it to me.

I also made one that turned my ringer up and played a song for when I lose my phone around the house. I can just text my phone 123findme and it will play a song even if I left it on vibrate mode.

Answer (score 6):

[Launching ConnectBot remote commands](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/are-there-any-command-line-ssh-clients-available-for-rooted-android-phones/1459#1459) in answer to another question.

Comment: Awesome! This solves a problem I have with the Wake on LAN plugins I have tried in the past. Now when I connect to my home WiFi, I can automatically send a WoL packet to my PC from my home content server.