# Are there any command line SSH clients available for rooted Android phones?

Tags: ssh, command-line

I of course have ConnectBot, but I'm looking for something I can script.

Edit: To clarify here, I'm not interested in *running* scripts from a terminal. What I want to do is run an SSH command in an automated/scheduled manner. Tasker and Locale Execute are the equivalent of cron, all I need is the 'ssh' command to run ***from*** the script.

Comment: For scriptability, I'm intending to use Tasker, either directly or via Locale Execute Plug-In http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.elmicha.app.LocaleExecute

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can install the [Terminal Emulator](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-android-term-jpAz.aspx) from google. Alternatively there is the [Better Terminal Emulator Pro](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-magicandroidapps-bettertermpro-ztq.aspx). I tried the Terminal Emulator on a non-rooted phone and it seemed to work fine.

Better Terminal Emulator Pro includes the [dropbear ssh client](http://www.magicandroidapps.com/wiki//index.php?title=SSH_Client), which can be launched from the command line or via a launcher. [More info from the authors](http://www.magicandroidapps.com/wiki//index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: Terminal Emulator force-closes consistently on my device, and apparently on lots of other peoples' devices. I also don't see any indication that it can be run from Tasker, or from the command line.

Comment: Turns out that Better Terminal Emulator Pro does include the dropbear client binary. Update your answer to include that info, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ideally, you should never use closed source software like Better Terminal Emulator Pro for anything cryptography related.  I'd recommend building dropbear ssh directly from source using the Cyanogen people's instructions, that's probably all BTEP did.

Comment: There are various open source android applications that install their own dropbear ssh client copy too, simply adding a symlink makes it work under Google's Terminal Emulator.

Comment: your link for terminal emulator from google  http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-android-term-jpAz.aspx   says  "This application seems to be removed from the Android Market"  I see no 'terminal emulator' by google in google play store. The first result in the google play store is Android terminal emulator by jack palevich but it has no ssh.

Answer (score 17):

Since my original question was about an ssh binary, and there is an answer for that, I'll accept that answer. However, there is another way to do what I wanted to do, kinda, that might be interesting to someone some day.

Tasker + ConnectBot can be used to execute arbitrary remote (or local, I guess, but Locale Execute is better for that) commands on a schedule.

Step 1: Set up your connection in ConnectBot.

- You can have duplicate connections in ConnectBot as long as they have different aliases. You have to rename one first (away from user@host) in order to create the second. Long Press and select "Edit Host" to perform these changes.
- You probably want to set up an ssh key without a password so that you can use this for automation.
- Once the connection actually works, you can use "Post-login automation" to add the remote commands you would like to run. Make sure there is a blank line at the end so that enter is sent after your last command. Use enter or ; to separate commands. I suggest using something like "echo hello" as a test until you are sure things are working, and "exit" at the end if you don't want to leave the connection open.
- Test this in isolation.

Step 2: Create a Tasker Task to call connectbot.

- Create a new Task in Tasker.
- Add an Action. From Misc, select "Action Intent"
- The fields are:

  - Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
  - Cat: Default
  - Data: ssh url, in the form of "ssh://user@host/#alias" (without the quotes). The alias, user and host here *must* match the alias you set up in Step 1.
  - Target: Activity
  - Click Test. Connectbot should open and your commands should execute on the remote host.

Step 3: Use this Task in Tasker however you would normally.

Comment: Is there a way to define the connection programatically, i.e., via Tasker and calling intents?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I don't recall exactly how I found the above Intent information, but it's basically a standard ssh URL. There are tools that can investigate Intents for apps, but I haven't used those.

Comment: I can add that if you remove the defaults for ConnectBot and have another ssh client installed (BTEP, for example) then ssh URLs will prompt for which app to use. This underscores that the above is something of a standard, both "VIEW" and the ssh format. The only thing specific to ConnectBot in this case is the #alias on the end.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old thread but wanted to +1 the comment about BTEP

I'm also using BTEP's ssh binary though I just call it from it's path instead of linking it
/data/data/com.magicandroidapps.bettertermpro/bin/ssh root@192.168.1.1

or generate a pair of keys and use public key authentication
/data/data/com.magicandroidapps.bettertermpro/bin/ssh -i /data/data/com.magicandroidapps.bettertermpro/home/.ssh/id_rsa -l root 192.168.1.1

I use the above command from SL4A r4 in various scripts and it works fine :)

before I could do this I needed to chmod a+x /data/data/com.magicandroidapps.bettertermpro/home/.ssh

once this is done and you backup/restore BTEP with TitaniumBackup the permissions are kept this means if you flash a new rom you can just restore the apps and all your scripts will work again

Answer (score 5):

I have successfully used [BotBrew Basil Experimental](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.botbrew.basil&hl=en) when running Android 4.4. BotBrew Basil Experimental is based on apt-get so after installing APK and bootstraping I just did `apt-get install dropbear` in a root shell to install SSH client (and server).

Answer (score 3):

Install terminal emulator and quickssh. Quickssh also includes dropbear. Does not cost you money, which it should not because this is surpassingly simple and it's based on dropbear.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid

`find -name ssh` user@host

Problem solved

Comment: looking at that program(sshdroid by beserker) I see only an ssh server gui. I then tried terminal emulator by jack, but see no ssh command added.   And looking for quickssh, in the play store, I don't see it. I see only quicksshd(by teslacoil) which has a small price and no doubt isn't an ssh client.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal Emulator absolutely supports scripts*. Don't believe the nay-sayers. You will need to learn BASH shell scripting, if you're not already familiar with it. Write a script and save it on your SD card. Run it with "sh filename" from Term.

If you clarify what it is you want to "script" having to do with SSH, I can likely give you a better recommendation.

*(It's actually the Android OS that supports BASH scripts, Terminal Emulator just grants you access to the Android shell, therefore scripting is inherently possible)

Comment: Updated the question. I don't want to call scripts with ssh, I want to call ssh from a script.

Comment: Exactly what I was getting at. Again, if you want to give some specifics I may be of more assistance.

Answer (score 2):

To call ssh from a script, all you need to do is set up ssh keys. There are a million how-tos on the web, but there's a page on the Cyanogen wiki that might be more suited to Android users. Once you set up keys, your general ssh command would look something like this: ssh -i /PATH/TO/KEY USER@IP

You can put that in a script, run it, and you will be logged in to the remote machine.

But here's what I think you're wanting to do. To only execute a command on a remote computer, just add it in single quotes: ssh -i /PATH/TO/KEY USER@IP 'command'

That executes the command on the remote machine without logging you in. You can run commands with options, pipes, redirects etc, but it's sometimes better to keep them simple. Except for the delay, it looks the same as executing the command(s) locally and can be used the same.

Locale Execute can be picky about what commands it will run. If it doesn't work, try putting it in a script and using Locale Execute to run the script.

Also, I have had problems with the ssh binary that is on the phone and found that moving it from /system/xbin and creating a link at /system/xbin/ssh to the Better Terminal Emulator ssh binary is more reliable. The BTEP binary is in /data/data/com.magicandroidapps.bettertermpro/bin/ssh

Answer (score 2):

[Botbrew](https://github.com/jyio/botbrew) is a package manager for Android, in the likes of `okpg` for BSD or more recently, like `APT` for Debian. Pretty nice. It doesn't have an ssh client as a package, but it doesn't look too hard to put in if you're used to building your own packages. And it could be useful as a toolchain for when you want to build other C/C++/etc binaries and libraries.

So albeit this isn't a direct answer, it may be useful for some people to know about.

Comment: Nice. It's also in the play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inportb.botbrew

Comment: Sadly, it looks like botbrew.com is down, which blocks installation.

Comment: That's weird, because I think the packages are hosted on github.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a terminal called Termux that you can apt install openssh in. Available on [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux), [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.termux), and [Github](https://github.com/termux/termux-app).

Comment: please link the app from Google play

Answer (score -1):

AndFTP can connect over any port you configure so I'm sure it could connect over SSH. But I'm not sure how easy it is to script usage of it. I use the app myself all the time for my hosting server and it works great.

Not sure if you can SSH with Terminal Emulator, but you could try it too. I use that app frequently for doing things I'm too lazy to do with ADB.

Comment: AndFTP is great. Is Terminal Emulator scriptable?

Comment: I don't think so, not without another app. As you mention above, Tasker is probably the way to go with this.

Answer (score -1):

Use an ssh plugin for Tasker? Don't need root or ssh binary then.

Comment: Name one? Your answer could be helpful then :)

Comment: There is "SSH Plugin Paid" for Tasker, but it is old and not anymore developed. The error handling is nearly not existing, so it is just ssh and not much more. But it works.

Answer (score -3):

If the simple ssh client is interesting to you, I made under Android-NDK Bionic library drobpear-ssh-client-only.
ftp://ftp.simtreas.ru/pub/my/dropbear/dropbear-ssh-only.tgz
sourse and ftp://ftp.simtreas.ru/pub/my/dropbear/ssh binary

Comment: This is not a generic answer sadly and will work only on one of x86/ARM/MIPS, probably ARM. Also the linked content will most probably disappear at some time. Most custom ROMs already include a working pure cmdline ssh client.