# How can I SSH into my Android without rooting it?

Tags: remote-control, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some SSH server for android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/is-there-some-ssh-server-for-android)

Are there free Android apps that would let me SSH into it remotely?

Related: Are there Android SSH client apps that would let me SSH into other computers from my Android?

Comment: I would totally tag this "ssh", but the stupid Stack Overflow controls don't let me create new tags.

Comment: ssh already exists, but I added it anyway

Comment: Your first question should be covered by the duplicate. Have you searched the Play Store for your second? There are lots, and very broad "Is there an app for X?" questions are not really a good fit for this site: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ssh+client&c=apps (also related is [Are there any command line ssh clients available for rooted android phones?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/are-there-any-command-line-ssh-clients-available-for-rooted-android-phones) which asks about scriptability of clients)