# Automatically load a text file a few minutes after the alarm goes off - is there an app for that?

Tags: automation

Is there a way (presumably via a 3rd party app) that I can set a particular text file to open at a set time, i.e. something I need to read on a daily basis can be set to load at 6.03 after the alarm has finished going off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do this through an app called Tasker.  Check out [Useful or cool Tasker recipes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/775/useful-or-cool-tasker-recipes), you may be able to modify one of those scripts to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use alarm clock plus, it allows you to set an app to launch when the alarm goes off. http://www.appbrain.com/app/alarm-clock-plusv2%E2%98%85/com.vp.alarmClockPlusDock

Answer (score 0):

as @MatthewRead said, it is possible using '[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)' and '[AutoAlarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoalarm)'. Need some customised scripts/Tasks need to be set!